# Will it always be safe to use "id" as a method name in an Objective-C protocol?

Tags: objective-c

On a client codebase I'm working on, someone has named a method in a protocol like so:-

```
- (NSString *)id;
```

I know it compiles fine, and I know it's not a reserved word in Objective-C (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009036/is-it-ok-to-use-id-as-a-property-name)), but still I'm slightly uneasy with this. Apart from aesthetic issues, I'm specifically worried about future-proofing: is this guaranteed to always be legal Objective-C?

I have to use the protocol, and I don't know if it's worth changing it across the board (and the conversations with the client about why I'm doing that).

Answer (score 1):

No. In particular, it is probably always going to be legal Objective-C, but the label "id" itself is a lot like the label "test": it is unwise to use it because it is almost guaranteed to clash with something else in the environment eventually. Your language is Objective-C, but any frameworks, imports, class extensions, etc. are almost bound to eventually involve something else called "id" later on down the road.

It can be irritating to track down a bug that results from, for example, deciding to port existing code to use some helpful framework, only to discover the either your "id" is overriding a value the framework expects, or that the framework/mixin/subclass/whatever is overriding or otherwise redefining it and you weren't aware.

I steer clear of what I consider universally overloaded labels like "doc", "test", "id", and "init" (when not already reserved in langX) in *every* language and environment I encounter. It seems that the use of any of these terms always ends in grief. (The grief of a massive search/replace, which isn't always as easy as simple text replacement in the code).

Comment: I agree it's bad style, and I'd never do it, but this is a very large existing codebase. Changing it is more than just a simple search/replace since "id" is an Objective-C type used everywhere. I'm trying to balance the pain of changing it with the risk of leaving it alone.

Comment: If it is deeply embedded in the codebase already then leaving it is your only practical choice. It may be possible to isolate its use, though, and begin aliasing it as something else in any new code (like `foo = id` wherever id is initially defined). Any maintenance changes to the old code can use the new symbol and you can eventually get rid of it -- but even remembering to do that can be more bookkeeping than its worth. Like nearly everything else "it depends". :-)